# Deleting multiple Auto scaling groups in one shot: AWS CLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have multiple Autoscaling groups which needs to be deleted. For eg: I have ASGs `awsLC1` `xyzLC2` `aLC3`. I have found them using AWS CLI with below query:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[? contains(AutoScalingGroupName,'LC')].AutoScalingGroupName" --output text
```

It gives me a list on console. However `delete-auto-scaling-group` only takes 1 ASG (auto scaling group) name in parameter.

How can I do that?

Any way to automate this using bash programming?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLI doesn't support deleting multiple ASGs. You can try a simple bash script:

```
$ for group in `aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations --query "LaunchConfigurations[?contains(LaunchConfigurationName,'LC')].[LaunchConfigurationName]" --output text`
> do
> echo $group
> done
```

Once you verify the groups, delete them:

```
$ for group in `aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations --query "LaunchConfigurations[?contains(LaunchConfigurationName,'LC')].[LaunchConfigurationName]" --output text`
> do
> aws autoscaling delete-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name $group
> done
```

**EDIT**

Based on @JordonPhillips input, you can use `-I` option of `xargs` to come up with a one liner:

```
aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations --query "LaunchConfigurations[?contains(LaunchConfigurationName,'LC')].[LaunchConfigurationName]" --output text | xargs -I aws autoscaling delete-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name
```

Comment: You could also use `xargs` to make this work as a one-liner

Comment: @JordonPhillips but the command accepts one argument only. So `xargs` is of no use.

Comment: You can use the `-I` option to have xargs execute the command once for each input.

Comment: @JordonPhillips, thanks. updated the answer. Wasn't aware of `-I` option.

Comment: I tried but getting following error. xargs: autoscaling: No such file or directory

Comment: aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations --query "LaunchConfigurations[?contains(LaunchConfigurationName,'LC')].[LaunchConfigurationName]" --output text | xargs -I aws autoscaling delete-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name
 which is not working. However loop approach has worked.

Comment: shouldnt it be `xargs -I {} aws autoscaling delete-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name {}` ?